# Flexible div height main content

Tags: jquery, css, twitter-bootstrap

I have created a web page using bootstrap. I am having trouble setting the main content area. I have set height in % and given a min-height. But when I click the menu item and load html pages using jquery load(), the div location moves between  main page and other pages.

Here is my main page code:

```js
  $(document).ready(function() {
    
      $(".content").load("defaultcontent.html");
    
      $(".about").click(function(e) {
       $(".content").load("about.html");
      });
    
      $(".home").click(function(e) {
       $(".content").load("defaultcontent.html");
      });
    
      $(".products").click(function(e) {
       $(".content").load("products.html");
      });
    
      $(".contact").click(function(e) {
       $(".content").load("contactus.html");
      });
    
     });
```

```css
    body {
     background-image:
      url("https://www.airmanchallenge.com/images/backgroundSite.jpg");
     color: white;
    }
    
    .navbar>a:hover {
    background-color: black;
     color: white;
    }
    
    .topnav >a:hover {
    background-color: black;
     color: white;
    }
    
    .content {
     height: auto;
     min-height: 400px;
    }
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
    <html>
    <head>
    <meta content="text/html; charset=utf-8" http-equiv="Content-Type" />
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
    <title>Sample Page</title>
    <link
     href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css"
     rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />
    <script type="text/javascript"
     src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.1.1.min.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript"
     src="https://code.jquery.com/ui/1.12.1/jquery-ui.min.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript"
     src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
    
    
    </head>
    <body>
     <header class="text-center">
      <h1>ABC Store</h1>
      <p>some description</p>
     </header>
    
     <nav role="navigation" class="navbar navbar-default">
      <!-- Collection of nav links and other content for toggling -->
      <div id="navbarCollapse" class="collapse navbar-collapse">
       <ul class="nav navbar-nav topnav">
        <li><a class="home">Home</a></li>
        <li><a class="products">Products</a></li>
        <li><a class="contact">Contact</a></li>
        <li><a class="about">About</a></li>
       </ul>
      </div>
     </nav>
    
     <div class="container">
      <div class="row">
       <span>
        <div class="row-sm-12 row-md-12 row-lg-12 content"
         style="background-color: lightblue;"></div>
       </span>
      </div>
     </div>
    
     <footer class="text-center"> &#169; ABC Group. All Rights
      Reserved </footer>
    </body>
    </html>
```

How shall I fix this? I am not able to get what is causing this.

I have hosted this website to show the current views.
http://sampledreamstore.000webhostapp.com

Answer (score 1):

This is called [margin collapse](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/CSS_Box_Model/Mastering_margin_collapsing). What you're seeing is the normal behavior (no margin collapse) on the home page content area, since the first child of `.content` is `strong`, which has no margin. But on the rest of the pages, the first child of `.content` is an `h2` which has a big top-margin that is collapsing outside of the parent.

To fix it, I would remove the `margin-top` on the `h2`'s on the sub-pages and replace it with a consistent `padding-top` in `.content`. You could also use an `h2` on all of the pages like you have on the sub-pages. Or you could apply `padding: 1px` or `border: 1px transparent` to `.content`, which will disable the margin collapse and keep it inside of `.content`.

Comment: If possible would you please let me know how I can make my content area accomodate all page contents without changing dimension.

Comment: @kromastorm what do you mean? The pages have different amounts of content. What do you want to happen instead of the content area size changing?

Comment: I will update the hosted web page. what is happening is this. my main content page will have lot more text and image. I will add scroll to it mostly. Rest of the pages may or may not have that much content. I do not want to content area to keep changing dimension everytime use clicks on other pages.

Comment: Updated the link: http://sampledreamstore.000webhostapp.com/        My current screen resolution is 1366* 768, I see the scrollbar created when I come to homepage everytime from other pages.

Comment: change `min-height` to `height` and add `overflow-y: scroll;`

Comment: Thanks. I used overflow-y: auto. it solved my problem. One query I have is will this work fine on mobile devices?

Comment: It looks like it should.